# How can I find the short path of a Windows directory/file?

Tags: windows-7

I need to use shortened path names for an application that I am using. For example I need `C:\PROGRA~1\` as opposed to `C:\Program Files`. The program can't handle spaces and won't accept quoted paths (e.g. `"C:\Program Files"`).

If it helps, I am using Windows 7. I can get access to any version since XP, if necessary.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Start, and type `cmd` in the run box.  Start cmd, and use `cd` to get to the folder you are interested in:

```
cd \
```

Then

```
dir /x

C:\>dir /x

13/10/2011  09:14 AM    <DIR>          DOCUME~1     Documents and Settings
13/10/2011  09:05 AM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
```

Comment: So you do this for every subfolder in the path?

Comment: @endolith The `/s` switch does subfolder recursion

Comment: I mean how do you display the entire 8.3 path?

Comment: @endolith See the answer below

Comment: @Paul This doesn't seem to work in Win10. Any ideas?

Comment: @AHungerArtist The short file names don't necessarily exist; their creation can be turned off.

Comment: @AHungerArtist An alternative that I've used on occasion is to "roll your own": create a directory junction.  This can be done with either the builtin `MKLINK.EXE` tool. or my option of choice, the Junction utility from Sysinternals: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction .  Open a command prompt in the directory containing the subdirectory with spaces in its name, and enter `Junction shortname "Long Name With Spaces"`.

Comment: You can do this in one command without `cd` like this: `dir C:\Path\To\Directory /X`

Comment: thank you, from 2021!

Comment: Note this will not work in PowerShell. You have to use the Command shell (cmd) specifically. See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631079/powershell-dir-command-options-not-working

Answer (score 67):

Create a bat file in some convenient directory

then you could copy+paste the short path from that path.

You could just run `command.com` and keep doing `cd` commands to your current directory too.

In Windows batch scripts, [`%~s1` expands path parameters to short names](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx). Create this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %~s1
```

I called mine `shortNamePath.cmd` and call it like this:

```
C:\> shortNamePath "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
c:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
```

Here's a version that uses the current directory if no parameter was supplied:

```
@ECHO OFF
if '%1'=='' (%0 .) else echo %~s1
```

Called without parameters:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk> shortNamePath
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
```

**Using `SET` and a named variable**

Windows Command Prompt has some conventions for handling variables
with spaces in their values that are somewhat hard to learn and understand,
especially if you have a Unix background. 
You can do

```
SET TESTPATH=c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

(with ***no*** quotes), or

```
SET "TESTPATH=c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

(note the non-intuitive placement of quotes); then

```
CALL :testargs "%TESTPATH%"
        ︙

:testargs
echo %~s1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Really useful, should be marked as answer!

Comment: Thanks!  Is it do-able using a SET command ? like SET AAA=C:\program files\what ever\another space in the middle\    to the short version

Comment: @Li3ro I couldn't figure out SET variable command way but I got pretty close, you can see it at the bottom of the answer just needs a little fix up. I'm not into batch script programming so I don't know how.

Comment: It is not doable this way. you need the for loop for this

Comment: This is more useful than the accepted answer

Comment: I created a `ShortName.bat` file with your code (added `pause`) into `shell:sendto` folder, then I can access it by right-clicking a file then `SendTo->ShortName`. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

**Here is a one liner**:

```
cmd /c for %A in ("C:\Program Files") do @echo %~sA
```

**Breakdown**:

- `cmd /c`  - Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter, carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
- `for %%parameter in (set) do` command - Conditionally perform a command several times.
- `echo` - Display messages on screen. `@` symbol is the same as `ECHO OFF` applied to the current line only.
- `%~s` - Expanded path contains short names only.

**Sources**:

- [CMD docummentation](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Nice!!!  You can replace "C:\Program Files" with . to get the short name for the current directory

Comment: When / why would you need the `cmd /c`?  If you’re in a Command Prompt window, you can just type the ``for %A in ("C:\Program Files") do @echo %~sA`` command, and if you type this into the “Run” dialog box, the result disappears before you can read it.

Comment: Nicely done; as @Scott points out, you don't need the `cmd /c` when running from `cmd`; you do need it from _PowerShell_, but then you also need to `'...'`-enclose the tokens after `/c`: `cmd /c 'for %f in ("C:\Program Files") do @echo %~sf'`

Answer (score 16):

I found very handy way to solve short pathname  of current directory (or anything else) if you have Powershell installed.

Just open powershell in current dir

- in cmd windows type powershell
- if you have folder open in gui you can type cmd.exe or powershell.exe directly in address bar of folder.

Then give command

```
(New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFolder(".").ShortPath
```

Origin of information: [https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ShortName-90a49303]

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `(New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFolder((Get-Location).Path).ShortPath` though, because your version would always return "C:\Windows\System32"

Answer (score 11):

The "short name" is really the old DOS 8.3 naming convention, so all the directories will be the first 6 letters followed by `~1` assuming there is only one name that matches, for example:

```
C:\ABCDEF~1    - C:\ABCDEFG I AM DIRECTORY
C:\BCDEFG~1    - C:\BCDEFGHIJKL M Another Directory
```

here is the only exception

```
C:\ABCDEF~1    - C:\ABCDEFG I AM DIRECTORY
C:\ABCDEF~2    - C:\ABCDEFGHI Directory as well
```

Comment: Not true.  Sometimes fewer characters are used, particularly if you are using asian characters, such as Korean.

Comment: I suppose finding out which one is which in the "exceptional" case is the point of the question - especially as the "exception" regularly occurs in every Windows 64 bit installation, where you may need to know which one out of `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` is `PROGRA~1` and which one is `PROGRA~2`. [Paul](http://superuser.com/users/89018/paul)'s answer solves that issue.

Comment: I have so many files that start with the same characters that after four of them (`...~4`) it started with what looks like hashing, e.g. `ABxxxx~1` where x was hexadecimal -- which isn't very easy to read.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the user can figure out the short names logically by looking at the long names? That’s not true.  If I create `ABCDEFGH-CAT`, it gets short name `ABCDEF~1`. If I then create `ABCDEFGH-DOG`, it gets short name `ABCDEF~2`. If I then delete `ABCDEFGH-CAT`, `ABCDEFGH-DOG`, still has short name `ABCDEF~2`. There’s no way to tell just by looking at the long names.

Comment: as said, the short name doesn't have to be the 6 first letters plus `~1`. See [the rule that Windows uses for generating short names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#VFAT_and_Computer-generated_8.3_filenames). And you can also set the short name manually with `fsutil`, so the two names may have no relation whatsoever. Let alone hard or soft links

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Ivan Schwartz's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1211528/461558), you can replace "C:\Program Files" with `%cd%` to get current dir:

```
cmd /c for %A in ("%cd%") do @echo %~sA
```

Answer (score 4):

```
C:\Users\abcd>subst z: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office365 Tools\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"

C:\Users\abcd>subst
Z:\: => C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office365 Tools\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
```

This is the easiest way I have used when dealing with files with spaces and this is accessible from file explorer too has all the same access privileges.

Comment: This is the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

**for windows 10 users**
**NONE** of these solutions was working for on my windows 10 laptop
since a key in the registry prohibited the creation of shortnames.. :

- Alt+r, type *regedit* to open the registry editor
- go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
- look for the *NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation* key : if the value is 0x00000001(1), then your system does not create any shortname for your folder/file
- in this case double clic on the *NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation* key,
- type 0 in the data field

**this is not retroactive** :) I mean you need to recreate the folder/file you need to access from your old app.. maybe something clever is possible though I don't know yet.

it seems they introduced this key to speed up filesystem operations.

source microsoft :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc959352(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Did this does not work.

Comment: Note that disabling 8 dot 3 is not only a performance improvement, it's part of the remediation for an IIS vulnerability: https://serverfault.com/questions/670658/fixing-the-iis-tilde-vulnerability (OK, you're probably (hopefully) not serving a public website from your laptop - this applies more on the server side)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use this awesome little tool called [PathCopyCopy](https://pathcopycopy.codeplex.com)

In a few clicks, you can get the long and short path of literally any folder from the contextual menu, e.g:

> Right-click in the destination folder => Path Copy => Short Path.

Done. It will be copied to your clipboard.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3TbT.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for %%i in (%*) do echo %%~si
pause
```

Save it as shortpath.bat , and then drag files on it.
Its result:

```
C:\PROGRA~1
C:\PROGRA~2
C:\PROGRA~3
C:\Python27
C:\Users
C:\Windows
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Calling it with `shortpath <file path>` is also OK.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the spaces with

```
%20
```

It's the way things are "translated", and spaces go into     %20.

If you really need alot, simply pop open your browser and type something like

```
test ";($#< and find the word test, and see that the space is %20 and so on...
```

Comment: I don't think you're right. This does not produce a positive outcome: `if exist C:\Program%20Files\ (echo exists)`

Comment: You're talking about something completely different. The main point is that directory and file names are truncated to 8 characters. The browser has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed node modules by running `npm install` on a boilerplate. While trying to delete those folders, windows does not allow us to delete them as path is too long to be able to handle.

After some of shallow research, I thought it would be right my own piece of code snippet to rename the folders from root to leaf so that it would throw any violation exception for this attempt as well.

It works for me. Following is the code for the C# project.

```cs
    public static int directoryCounterIndex = 0;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = @"D:\Studies\MeanStack\a\nodem";
        RenameDirectories(dirPath);
    }

    private static void RenameDirectories(string dirPath)
    {
        directoryCounterIndex += 1;
        var newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + directoryCounterIndex.ToString();
        Directory.Move(dirPath, newPath);
        var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(newPath);
        foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
        {
            RenameDirectories(subDirectory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.