# Windows: make application installed in Program Files seen like it has no spaces

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, path, matlab

I have Matlab installed in 'Program Files', and I need to install the toolbox that requires a path without any spaces. The problem is I can't perform reinstallation of that program in another location. Is there any way to make application is seen by other programs or dependencies like it is installed in a folder without spaces? I considered making some links or editing register entries but I don't have any idea how to deal with that.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us exactly what steps you are taking to install this “toolbox” and what messages you are seeing, preferably with screenshots. Spaces in a path are NOT the problem. Typically paths are surrounded with quotes whenever this IS an “issue.”

Answer (score 0):

The tool to use is
[mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink),
and the call you are looking for is:

```
mklink /J C:\myfolder "C:\my path\with blanks"
```

This will create a hard link pointing to the directory, also known as a
directory junction,
and will make Windows work with `C:\myfolder` as if it was
the other directory `C:\my path\with blanks`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make links, etc.  Windows has had "short file names" that fit the old DOS 8.3 format hidden in the background since Win95.

For example, `C:\Program Files` is really `C:\PROGRA~1\`

Check out [How can I find the short path of a Windows directory/file?](https://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file/728792)