# How do I run a multiple commands with spaces using cmd and ampersands?

Tags: cmd.exe

I am trying to run a sequence of commands using the `cmd` command, the `/k` switch, and `&&` to separate each command in the sequence.

For example, I would like to run this command to change to one folder, and then to the next:

`cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" && "cd C:\Program Files\Windows Mail"`

But this doesn't work - it changes the folder only to Microsoft Office, and then stops.

How do I get this done?

Edit:

Actually, @señor-csmasmas is correct - my earlier example doesn't really demonstrate the problem.

The problem actually shows up when I run a command that has spaces in the path, followed by a command to change a directory.

For example, if you create a bat file which copies a file (let's call it copyfile.bat), and place the bat file in a folder with spaces, then call the cmd command like so:

`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Test Folder\copyfile.bat" && "cd C:\Some Other Folder"`

You will see that the current directory is not changed to C:\Some Other Folder.

Comment: A better example would be helpful even though @Hannu has already answered your question.  Your example is pointless.  One other point, if you can't make it work using file names with spaces.. you can always use the [short file name](https://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Using sort name would do fine, but just understanding where the ***"`double quotes are needed`"*** would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Edit

> *The problem actually shows up when I run a command that has spaces in the path, followed by a command to change a directory.*
>
> *For example, if you create a bat file which copies a file (let's call it copyfile.bat), and place the bat file in a folder with spaces, then call the cmd command like so:*
>
> ```
> C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Test Folder\copyfile.bat" && "cd > C:\Some Other Folder"
>
> :: try :: 
> C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k "call "C:\Test Folder\copyfile.bat" && cd /d "C:\Some Other Folder""
> ```

Edit //

---

```bash
cmd /k "cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" && cd "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail""
```

---

Try to visualize how your commands and the operator will look likes between double quotes where necessary in a single *`cmd /k "command "with" operator and another command "with""`*

```
cmd /k "

       cd /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" 
       && 
       cd /d "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail"

       "

cmd /k " command "path #1" && command "path #2" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Before windows was DOS and before that was CP/M.

CP/M would generally only run single commands.

DOS increasingly had more and more abilities to split CPU usage for separate processes, thus you could run a secondary command.com from the primary level with its own environment.

So Windows inherited a need for several ways to call command processes, and thus 3 master switches still survive.

> command.com should be dead
> [image]

The new kid on the block is cmd.exe at it defaults to same  behaviour as /K (keep active) and you can exit back to current cmd level ***here is your problem***

[image]

However we often want to let a cmd run and return **c**onsole **c**ontrol & **c**ontinue so that is `/c`

So what is the third ? It is not listed !

[image]

[image]

so /c and /r are synonymous both act as run and continue

OK that was a diversion and does not answer the question which is potentially similar to this problem that the commands in a line are run before used (non delayed execution)

[image]

We could expect %CD% to report c:\users but clearly was not

### So to your answer

You want to move to another location and start a fresh Konsole then you need to change the order and method

**you have**

```
cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" && "cd C:\Program Files\Windows Mail"
```

So this works (may well be overkill ?)

[image]

`cmd /c start " " cmd /r "cd /d "c:\program files" && cmd /k" && cd /d "c:\users"`

we start a secondary process that will /run `cd` and `/k` then we change to another cwd and it should work the other way round too

**So try this answer**

```
start "Office Dir" cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" && cd "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail"
```

optionally add a  `&& dir`  to verify during test

If what you are after is two seperate consoles like this
[image]

then use this order

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" && start "office" cmd /k && cd /d "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail" && start "Mail" cmd /k
```